# If ldap_connect fails, variable assigned to it should be false?

Tags: php

I have a website that uses LDAP authentication.  I have two active directory servers for redundancy.  If the primary server is down, authentication should be handled by the back-up server.  I tried using the following to achieve this:

```
  $LDAP_SERVER = "10.100.10.1";
  $LDAP_SERVER_BACKUP = "10.100.10.2";

  $ldap_mycorp = ldap_connect($LDAP_SERVER);

  if(!$ldap_mycorp){
    $ldap_mycorp = ldap_connect($LDAP_SERVER_BACKUP);
  }
```

But I noticed that if the connection to the primary server failed, 'ldap_connect($LDAP_SERVER)' returns a resource id instead of false, which means the if statement is never used.

I came up with a workaround for this by adding some additional code later in the script, but there must be a solution to handle the problem within the above context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host name parameter can be a space separated list of host names. This means that the LDAP code will talk to a backup server if the main server is not operational. There will be a delay while the code times out trying to talk to the main server but things will still work.

```
$LDAP_SERVERS = "10.100.10.1 10.100.10.2";
$ldap_mycorp = ldap_connect($LDAP_SERVERS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php

I have no idea what it returns when there is no error, but it should give you a step in the right direction. With the answer given to connect automatically to multiple servers if the previous failed, you should still check if the connection didn't have any errors ;)